# Copy record to another column based on duplicated condition in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-groupby

Pardon me if similar question is already asked. I am a newbie and trying to get my hands on with Python.

I have a below data frame that is generated from a pandas function `DataFrame.duplicated()`, based on 'Loc'(groupby) and 'Category'. Only repeated records are marked as True/False rest are marked as 'Not Applicable'

```
Number  Loc    Category        Date            Only_Dupes
----------------------------------------------------------
1        A     jetski        01/01/2020       Not Applicable
2        A     kayak         01/02/2020       Not Applicable
3        A     jetski,kayak  01/04/2020       Not Applicable
4        B     jetski        01/05/2020       False
5        B     jetski        01/07/2020       True
6        C     kayak         01/08/2020       False
7        C     kayak         01/09/2020       True
8        C     jetski        01/10/2020       Not Applicable
```

Code to identify duplicates are:

```
comp1 = df.duplicated(['Loc','Category'])
comp2 = df.groupby(['Loc','Category'])['Category'].transform('count').gt(1)
df['Only_Dupes'] = np.where(comp2,comp1,'Not Applicable')
```

My expectation is to create another column 'Source_Date', that should represent a source date of a record only of they are duplicated and rest can be blank.

Expected Dataframe:

```
Number  Loc    Category       Date       Only_Dupes    Source_date
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        A     jetski       01/01/2020    Not Applicable       
2        A     kayak        01/02/2020    Not Applicable       
3        A     jetski,kayak 01/04/2020    Not Applicable
4        B     jetski       01/05/2020    False          01/05/2020
5        B     jetski       01/07/2020    True           01/05/2020
6        C     kayak        01/08/2020    False          01/08/2020 
7        C     kayak        01/09/2020    True           01/08/2020
8        C     jetski       01/10/2020    Not Applicable
```

Please let me know if any more clarification is required. Thank you for your assistance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `duplicated` with `keep=False` and `.loc` for assignment.

```
s = df.duplicated(['Loc','Category'],keep=False)


df.loc[s,'SrcDate'] = df.groupby([s,'Loc'])['Date'].transform('min')

print(df)

   Number Loc      Category       Date      Only_Dupes    SrcDate
0       1   A        jetski 2020-01-01  Not-Applicable        NaT
1       2   A         kayak 2020-01-02  Not-Applicable        NaT
2       3   A  jetski,kayak 2020-01-04  Not-Applicable        NaT
3       4   B        jetski 2020-01-05           False 2020-01-05
4       5   B        jetski 2020-01-07            True 2020-01-05
5       6   C         kayak 2020-01-08           False 2020-01-08
6       7   C         kayak 2020-01-09            True 2020-01-08
7       8   C        jetski 2020-01-10  Not-Applicable        NaT
```